# read.csv to import more than 2105 columns?

Tags: r, import, dataframe, read.csv

**Leaving question for archival purposes only.**
(Read.csv did read in all columns, I just did not see them in the preview when opening the data.frame)

Related to this question: 
[Maximum number of columns that can be read using read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195978/maximum-number-of-columns-that-can-be-read-using-read-csv)
I would like to import a csv file into R that contains about 3200 columns (100 rows). I am used to working with data.frames and read.csv, but my usual approach failed because

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE)
```

only imported the first 2105 columns. It did not display an error message.

- How can I readin a csv file with more than 2105 columns?

  - *without specifying column classes*
  - into a data frame
  - the file contains different data types (dates, strings, numbers, ..)
  - speed is not my biggest concern

I did not manage to apply the solutions in [Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r/15058684#15058684) to my situation. Tried this, but it does not seem to work without information on column classes:

```
df <- as.data.frame(scan("data.csv",sep=','))
```

There are already several questions about reading in large datafiles with millions of rows/columns and how to speed up the process, but my files are much smaller, so I am hoping that there is an easier solution that I overlooked.

Comment: did you try fread from the package data.table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

data <- fread("data.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am going to close this question because I made a stupid mistake when posting. read.csv actually did import all columns, I just did not see them in the data.frame preview.

Comment: No problem. In any case, I recommend you stick to `fread{data.table}` because it is by far the fastest way of reading `.csv` files into R.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP)*.

Read.csv did read in all columns, I just did not see them in the preview when opening the data.frame